# Convert Multiple List to Single Master Child object List Using Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have 2 objects which need to be converted to Dto object using automapper.
Those 2 objects are

```
    public class Parent
    {
        public int ParentID { get; set;}
        public string ParentCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public int ChildID { get; set; }
        public int ParentID { get; set;}
        public string ChildCode { get; set; }
    }
```

And 2 Dto objects

```
    public class ParentDto
    {
        public int ParentID { get; set; }
        public string ParentCode { get; set; }
        public List<ChildDTO> ListChild { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildDto
    {
        public int ChildID { get; set; }
        public string ChildCode { get; set; }
    }
```

Need to convert 2 set of list

```
List<Parent> ListParent
List<Child> ListChild
```

To

```
List<ParentDto> ListParentDto
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have multiple sources, my solution was a method like

```
    public static List<ParentDto> MapToDto(List<Parent> parents, List<Child> childs)
    {
        List<ParentDto> parentDtos = new List<ParentDto>();
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {

            cfg.CreateMap<Parent, ParentDto>().BeforeMap((s, d) =>
            {
                d.ListChild = new List<ChildDto>();
                foreach (var child in childs.Where(c => c.ParentID == s.ParentID))
                {
                    d.ListChild.Add(new ChildDto { ChildCode = child.ChildCode, ChildID = child.ChildID });
                }
            }).ForMember(dest => dest.ParentID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ParentID)).ForMember(dest => dest.ParentCode, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ParentCode));
        });

        IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        foreach (var p in parents)
        {
            var source = p;
            var destination = mapper.Map<Parent, ParentDto>(source);
            parentDtos.Add(destination);
        }

        return parentDtos;
    }
```

Comment: Don't understand the following code ->
    foreach (var child in childs.Where(c=>c.ParentID==s.ParentID)) ->
what is childs ???

Comment: It works.. But i have lots of parent child Dto's ... can you help me with a generic method? thanks in advance bro.

Comment: Great :) Help me marking my answer as useful pls. Do you have more class's with this format is what you are saying? and that you want a generic method that will receive 2 lists like the one i posted and returns a result?

Comment: One solution is, to do 2 interfaces, IParent and IChild, and in the method the input params will be List<IParent> and List<IChild> with this you can have different class's but because they all implement the same interface that have the base params the method becomes generic.